# How do I know whether Jenkins is installed by yum or not?

Tags: jenkins, yum

OS : Centos 7
Current Jenkins version : **2.191**

---

I want to know if I should `yum update jenkins` or mannually replace `jenkins.war`.
I have no clue how it's installed.
Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
rpm -qa|grep -i jenkins
```

If as result you see nothing, Jenkins is installed by hand. If you see some line it mean Jenkins is installed via downloaded rpm or via `yum`. In this case it's OK to try `yum update jenkins`